# Invalid Number of Arguments when trying to add arrays inside a list using python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to understand why I get invalid number of argument in the below code and if there is a way to fix it.

here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

acc_reading = []

a = np.array([0.11e+00, 1.11e-08, 1.11e-02])
b = np.array([0.12e+00, 1.22e-08, 2.22e-02])
c = np.array([3.11e+00, 3.18e-08, 3.33e-02])
d = np.array([3.41e+00, 4.18e-08, 4.31e-02])
e = np.array([0.55e+00, 1.55e-08, 5.31e-02])
f = np.array([0.66e+00, 1.66e-08, 3.66e-02])
g = np.array([0.66e+00, 1.66e-08, 3.66e-02])
h = np.array([0.66e+00, 1.66e-08, 3.66e-02])

ab = np.add(a,b)
cd = np.add(c, d)
ef = np.add(e, f)
i = np.add(g, h)

acc_reading.append(ab)
acc_reading.append(cd)
acc_reading.append(ef)
acc_reading.append(i)

kk = np.add(acc_reading[0], acc_reading[1], acc_reading[2], acc_reading[3])
```

The output of the above code is:
ValueError: invalid number of arguments

Comment: Did you read https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html already?

Comment: I am passing using acc_reading as a place holder to store my data. Actually, I get no errors if I do ab = np.add(acc_reading[0], acc_reading[1], acc_reading[2]). Also, array is defined in my original code.

Comment: Now you should get an error "'module' object is not callable" for `array(...)`. Did you mean `np.array` instead of just `array`? Please show an actual [mre].

Comment: @mkrieger1 you can check the code now.

Comment: What are you trying to do passing 4 `acc_reading` elements to `np.add`?  `np.add` takes 2 arguments (arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs for `np.add` and `np.sum`

---

Your lists - 4 terms of size 3

```
In [213]: acc_reading
Out[213]: 
[array([2.30e-01, 2.33e-08, 3.33e-02]),
 array([6.52e+00, 7.36e-08, 7.64e-02]),
 array([1.21e+00, 3.21e-08, 8.97e-02]),
 array([1.32e+00, 3.32e-08, 7.32e-02])]
```

sum all values to one:

```
In [214]: np.sum(acc_reading)
Out[214]: 9.5526001622
```

sum rows and columns - treating `acc_reading` as (3,4) array:

```
In [215]: np.sum(acc_reading, axis=0)
Out[215]: array([9.280e+00, 1.622e-07, 2.726e-01])
In [216]: np.sum(acc_reading, axis=1)
Out[216]: array([0.26330002, 6.59640007, 1.29970003, 1.39320003])
```

Your attempt to use `np.add` (which you used correctly earlier)

```
In [217]: np.add(acc_reading[0], acc_reading[1], acc_reading[2], acc_reading[3])
     ...: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-217-52b8f942b588>", line 1, in <module>
    np.add(acc_reading[0], acc_reading[1], acc_reading[2], acc_reading[3])
TypeError: add() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

giving it just 2 arrays:

```
In [218]: np.add(acc_reading[0], acc_reading[1])
Out[218]: array([6.750e+00, 9.690e-08, 1.097e-01])
```

a more direct way:

```
In [220]: arr = np.array([a+b, c+d, e+f, g+h])
In [221]: arr
Out[221]: 
array([[2.30e-01, 2.33e-08, 3.33e-02],
       [6.52e+00, 7.36e-08, 7.64e-02],
       [1.21e+00, 3.21e-08, 8.97e-02],
       [1.32e+00, 3.32e-08, 7.32e-02]])
In [222]: arr.sum()
Out[222]: 9.5526001622
```